# What's wrong with this code to determine if odd numbers are in a number list?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
def is_odd(number):
    """The function returns True if the number is odd, 
    False otherwise.
    """
    if number %  2 == 1:
        return True
    return False


def contains_odd_number(number_list):
    """The function returns True if number_list contains
    at least one odd number, False otherwise.
    """
    for num in number_list:
        if is_odd(num) != True:
            return False
        return True
```

Comment: de-indent `return True` or your loop will stop at first iteration no matter what

Comment: use `any(x % 2 for x in number_list)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems overcomplex & broken. One big issue is the indentation inside your loop.

Well, scratch that and write the function as follows using `any`:

```
def contains_odd_number(number_list):
    return any(x % 2 for x in number_list)
```

that's way more pythonic & performant. `any` stops as soon as an odd number is found in the list.

Comment: It can't be posible haha, you always bet me for just seconds, very good answer, I was thinking in the same, but always... yours is shorter. Plus one

Comment: thanks :) I took my time commenting and explaining what's wrong before answering (and also checked for exact duplicate).

Comment: that's why you rule as user here... keep going like this

Answer (score 2):

Reverse the logic. You know there is an odd number when you find the first, but you don't know that there isn't an odd one when you find the first even one:

```
for num in number_list:
    if is_odd(num):
        return True
return False  # only return False after you checked all
```

Comment: what? please read my comment

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Check the OP's logic! De-indenting won't fix the algorithm.

Answer (score 2):

You can simplify a lot your issue, don't be afraid to the boolean values, just return them:

in `is_odd` you can directly return the result

```
def is_odd(number):
    """The function returns True if the number is odd, 
    False otherwise.
    """
    return number %  2 != 0
```

And here, with a little of comprehension, and a good use of any:

```
def contains_odd_number(number_list):
    """The function returns True if number_list contains
    at least one odd number, False otherwise.
    """
    return(any(is_odd(x) for x in number_list))

print(contains_odd_number([2,2,2,1]))
```

-> True

Answer (score 0):

this is a logical error in

```
for num in number_list:
        if is_odd(num) != True:
            return False
        return True
```

you can solve this using a flag that you set to 1 if there is an odd number found in the list else it stays 0 if there is no odd number found in the iteration through the list

when the iteration through all list elements is finished you query the flag, if it is 1 the list contains an od number

```
        flag = 0
for num in number_list:
        if is_odd(num) == True:
            flag = 1

if flag == 1

    print ...
```

Answer (score 0):

contains_odd_number() is returning after the first iteration of the for loop.
In order to have it loop through the whole list, you'll need to move your default return out of the loop.

Resulting in the following:

```
def contains_odd_number(number_list):
    """The function returns True if number_list contains
    at least one odd number, False otherwise.
    """
    for num in number_list:
        if is_odd(num) != True:
            return False
    return True
```